# How to compile OpenCV 4.4 with FFmpeg for android?

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile OpenCV-4.4 for android with FFmpeg support. I tried following this [link](https://github.com/xuchong/android-opencv-ffmpeg). But the problem here is that the CMake scripts are entirely different. I searched on google a lot but could not find any link that resolves my issue. The problem that I'm facing is that when I run CMake script it does not find the FFmpeg libs that I have compiled. I think it is not even checking if the libs are available or not. I tried to modify the CMakeLists.txt in OpenCV but it did not resolve the issue. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into one of these
https://jayrambhia.com/blog/ffmpeg-opencv-android
https://gist.github.com/jayrambhia/4ede34930c9a067ea3f8